# Rewrite rules not working in WordPress

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I'm trying to add the new rewrite rules using the rewrite API:

```
 add_rewrite_rule('product/([A-Z0-9]{10})', 'index.php/product/?asin=$1', 'bottom');
 add_rewrite_rule('product/(([A-Za-z0-9_])*)', 'index.php/product/?product=$1', 'bottom');
 add_rewrite_rule('compare/((([A-Z0-9]{10}),?)*)', 'index.php/compare/?asin=$1', 'bottom');
 add_rewrite_rule('categories/(([A-Za-z0-9]|\-|\_)*)', 'index.php/categories/?subcategory=$1', 'bottom');
```

After the permalink is updated it adds the following lines to the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^product/([A-Z0-9]{10}) /index.php/product/?asin=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^product/(([A-Za-z0-9_])*) /index.php/product/?product=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^compare/((([A-Z0-9]{10}),?)*) /index.php/compare/?asin=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^categories/(([A-Za-z0-9]|\-|\_)*) /index.php/categories/?subcategory=$1 [QSA,L]
```

resulting to the following `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^product/([A-Z0-9]{10}) /index.php/product/?asin=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^product/(([A-Za-z0-9_])*) /index.php/product/?product=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^compare/((([A-Z0-9]{10}),?)*) /index.php/compare/?asin=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^categories/(([A-Za-z0-9]|\-|\_)*) /index.php/categories/?subcategory=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

But when I tried to access the following URL:

```
http://example.com/product/ABCDE324AB
```

It doesn't seem to work. I always get a page not found page. Any ideas?

Comment: is it a wordpress or server 404 page?

Comment: Once you have made any changes, don't forget to goto Settings > Permalinks and click Save to flush the rewrite rules.

Comment: yeah I've already flushed the rewrite rules by using the 'post name' permalink and then saving it but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 11):

What I understand from the above is you have .htaccess file and also correct code written in to the same file but still getting 404 issue. Let me tell you why. Your server not allowing .htaccess file to read or override permission. So how can you give this permission? Open your Apache httpd.conf file serch for AllowOverride now you can see it is present several times. check for below comment in to the same file:

```
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None
```

Just replace `AllowOverride None` by `AllowOverride All`

Now restart `APACHE` and it should work

Comment: This can also help you:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: it seems like the override is actually working because when I referenced a file that's outside of wordpress it was actually able to follow the rewrite rules. I just don't know why it wouldn't work with wordpress pages.

Comment: ok so do one thing. have backup of your htacces file and remove all code and add default htaccess code to this file. then go to permalink page and select default permalink. after that access the site I am sure site will work. Then try with other permalink setup.

Comment: this doesn't work either

Comment: You mean, you are not able to access the site with default permalink?

Comment: the default permalink works when I enter something like site.com?page_id=7 the custom rewrite rules that I added still doesn't work. It won't really work if I just use the default permalink but if I use the post name permalink it doesn't work either

Comment: which plugin you are using for rewrite rules?